# Nesting IIF in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I have the expression below running as my BG colour
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) MOD 2 =1,"#FCDFFF","Transparent")

But there are columns identified for additional formatting. For example, I want to colour a particular row base on a condition but knowing that I already have the above expression running across all rows how do I make that a reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want various checks, it's easiest to use a `Switch` expression.

I have set up a simple test based on your scenario:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now say I want to keep the alternating colour, but also highlight any values over 100 as red.

Change the BackgroundColor property expression to:

```
=Switch(Fields!Value.Value > 100, "Red"
    , RowNumber(Nothing) MOD 2 =1, "#FCDFFF"
    , True, Nothing)
```

This way, you keep the alternating colour but the first check takes precedence:

[image]

You can add more tests to the `Switch` as required.

Also, note that I have changed `"Transparent"` to `Nothing` in the expression - `"Transparent"` will actually work but gives a runtime warning:

> [rsInvalidColor] The value of the BackgroundColor property for the
>   text box ‘Value’ is “Transparent”, which is not a valid
>   BackgroundColor.

Using `Nothing` gives the required result without any warnings.